# Recreate heatmap

Tags: r, heatmap

I have the following data set in test.csv (6500 rows)...

```
Field 1 Field 2 Field 3 Field 4 Field 5 Field 6 Field 7 Field 8 Field 9 Field 10 Field 11 Field 12 Field 13 Field 14 Field 15 Field 16 Field 17 Field 18
1   1     1   1   0   0   1   0    1       1       1       0        1         0         0   1   0   0     1
2   1     1   1   0   0   1   0    1       1       1       0        1         0         0   1   0   0     1
3   1     1   1   0   0   1   0    1       1       1       0        1         0         0   1   0   0     1
4   1     1   1   0   0   1   0    1       1       1       0        1         0         0   1   0   0     1
5   1     1   1   0   0   1   0    1       1       1       0        1         0         0   1   0   0     1
6   1     1   1   0   0   1   0    1       1       1       0        1         0         0   1   0   0     1
7   1     1   1   0   0   1   0    1       1       1       0        1         0         0   1   0   0     1
8   1     1   1   0   0   1   0    1       1       1       0        1         0         0   1   0   0     1
9   1     1   1   0   0   1   0    1       1       1       0        1         0         0   1   0   0     1
```

I need to recreate the layout and format of this heatmap.

[image]

The legend and y axis label (Rows / observations) look like they were added outside of R, but so far, here is what I have done...

```
library(RColorBrewer)
# Read in dataset
df <- read.csv("test2.csv")

# Set as integer matrix
m <- as.matrix(df[, -1])

# Create colors
blackgrey <- c("black", "grey")
pal <- colorRampPalette(blackgrey)(100)

# Create heatmap
heatmap(m, Rowv = NA, Colv = NA, scale="column", col = pal)
```

Which yielded...

[image]

How do I change the bounds of the y axis units (instead of counting from 1, skip every 2000). Also, can I move this to the left like the heatmap I am trying to replicate?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The main thing I think can be improved based on Florian's comment is giving us data. Please do not post an image of code: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3358272.

Comment: I reposted a table. There are about 6500 row in total.

Comment: Your code is still not reproducible. It does not run because I don't have `"test2.csv"`. You could try to make an example using a subset of your data. `dput()` could be useful.

Comment: test.csc is the table I posted. There are no errors or issues with the map. I'm just asking how you would modify it's layout.